# How can i stop my html form to redirect on google form?

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, google-forms

I have connected my html form to google form but when i submitted the data it gets redirected on google form page i don't want that instead i want a success message if get submitted successfully or error message if not

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000)

```js
if(succes){
redirect
}
else{
error
}
```

so what are you asking will you please elaborate

Comment: Like i want my web form to submit in my gmail using php how can i do it

Comment: https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000
here is complete guid of google form submisiion